# Is there flash support for a Radeon hd 4650 agp video card in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: flash, radeon, adobe

I recently upgraded my video card from an evga geforce 6200 to a Radeon HD 4650 agp video card. After doing some research, I found that this Radeon card was basically the best agp card available, and it had flash support (according to the adobe flash website) for gpu acceleration. However, after re-installing 12.04 and the recommended driver via Jockey, flash is still choppy and hogs the cpu resources. Any suggestions? I've had some trouble finding information anywhere.

Also, I've got a new power supply on the way which will be a 400W (the specified "minimum" required according to the AMD specs). It will be replacing the existing 170W psu. Could my troubles be due to an insufficient power supply? Everything else seems to work well graphically. I just want flash support so I can stream smooth videos. Thanks for any help!

Computer specs:

Dell Dimension 4550
 
CPU: 3.0Ghz Pentium 4 with hyperthreading
 
1.5 Gigs RAM
AGP video card slot

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to answer my own question. I stumbled upon a thread that says gpu hardware acceleration has long since ended with Adobe Flash Player in Linux. Everything after 10.2 or 10.3 does not have the feature. Adobe should go die somewhere.

Comment: Blame Apple for killing flash, but it's technology.. and HTML5 should now be their focus.